# GIMP - how to fold all layers in list?

Tags: gimp, layers

I am working a lot with 3rd person PSDs in GIMP. They usually contain a lot of layers and by default they are all unfolded in layer tree window. How could I collapse all layers so I will only see top-level ones? Because I am repeadelly closing 40 layers and there is no "collapse all" options.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are talking about layer-groups, and that you want to collapse all groups (and any sub-groups) so that only top-level layers and layer-groups are shown in the Layers Dialog.

Unfortunately, there is no way to collapse-all groups at the moment - the UI does not provide such a function and it cannot be implemented from a script/plug-in either.

You could report this as a bug or enhancement request - see http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-introduction-bugs.html

Answer (score 0):

As [suggested](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/62651/gimp-how-to-fold-all-layers-in-list#answer-62842), I filed a [bug report on Gnome Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=779961). Having lots of layers & groups, I had similar issues with the layers dialogue being slow.

I propose 2 solutions:

- Have all layer groups be collapsed / folded by default
- Have a collapse all and uncollapse all button

Comment: These are workarounds rather than solutions - they hide the actual problem by reducing the number of items shown, but don't attempt to reduce the computational complexity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory) of scrolling. The bug is a good starting point, though - and even if we figure we can't reduce the complexity class, reducing the time (and thus increasing scrolling speed) by a fixed ratio can be useful.